# How to create a service using Google cloud endpoint which take a json value in input parameter

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-endpoints

I wanted to create a service which can accept JSON as an input to my endpoint. eg.

```
 [{ "name": "Ram","event": "processed" },
 {"name": "Raj", "event": "click" }] .
```

Tried some of the possible ways, cloud endpoints are not supporting arrays or any array related types to use.  I tried it to convert the json to string but it's not working for me.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an invalid JSON. Try validating it [**here**](http://jsonlint.com/). As you can see, you will encounter a parsing error.

[image]

Change all occurrences of `“` with `"`

```
[
    {
        "name": "Ram",
        "event": "processed"
    },
    {
        "name": "Raj",
        "event": "click"
    }
]
```

and now you have a valid JSON.

[image]

More details on JSON can be found **[here](http://www.json.org/)**.

Comment: Thanks to point out typo mistake  I update it but still not able to  create a  serivce which accept json as a input.

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) stating where exactly it goes wrong?